# Retrieve latest list of data base on date created

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to retrieve latest record list base on the date created, below is my query and from the query if I remove the `datecreated=(select max (datecreated) from staffmovement)` I am able to retrieve the list of date but if the line is included there was no data retrieved.

```
select max(c.datecreated) as datecreated
    ,c.DATEMOVE
    ,C.STAFFMOVEMENTTYPECODE
    ,A.STAFFNO
    ,a.STAFFNAME
    ,a.JOINDATE
    ,a.JOINDATECOMPANY
    ,b.JOINDATESUBSIDIARY
    ,b.CONFIRMDATESUBSIDIARY
    ,b.PERMANENTEMPDATE
    ,b.PERMANENTEMPDATESUBSIDIARY
    ,a.contractstartdate
    ,a.CONTRACTEXDATE
    ,a.LASTWORKDAY
    ,a.RESIGNDATE
    ,a.retirementdate
from staff a
    ,staffextra b
    ,staffmovement c
    ,staffmovementtype d
where a.staffno = b.staffno
    and a.staffno = c.staffno
    and D.STAFFMOVEMENTTYPECODE = C.STAFFMOVEMENTTYPECODE
    and a.stafftype not in ('8' ,'9' ,'10' ,'11' ,'12' )
    and c.staffmovementtypecode not in ('25' ,'26' ,'27' ,'37' ,'97' ,'78' )    
    and a.STAFFNO = 'KT0798'
    and a.status <> 1
    and DATECREATED = (
        select MAX(DATECREATED)
        from STAFFMOVEMENT
        )
group by c.datecreated
    ,c.DATEMOVE
    ,C.STAFFMOVEMENTTYPECODE
    ,A.STAFFNO
    ,a.STAFFNAME
    ,a.JOINDATE
    ,a.JOINDATECOMPANY
    ,b.JOINDATESUBSIDIARY
    ,b.CONFIRMDATESUBSIDIARY
    ,b.PERMANENTEMPDATE
    ,b.PERMANENTEMPDATESUBSIDIARY
    ,a.contractstartdate
    ,a.CONTRACTEXDATE
    ,a.LASTWORKDAY
    ,a.RESIGNDATE
    ,a.retirementdate
```

Comment: You are using c.datecreated and DATECREATED in your query. Are those supposed to be the same? If not, DATECREATED belongs to which table?

Comment: yes, they are the same. datecreated belongs to staffmovement table.

Comment: In that case, why not use c.datecreated in your where clause? Also, you keep changing styles from CAPS to no CAPS... You should try to rewrite your query so that it has an uniform naming style and repost it. Also, a database structure would be useful in order for us to be able to help